# How can multiple client programs can share messages with each other simultaneously?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, unix, networking

I'm trying to implement distance vector routing using unix sockets and c++.

I am running multiple instance of client programs (each is given the IP of a virtual network interface ,so it can bind to that IP). Each client is trying to emulate a router. So far, it does this->

part-1) Loads an initial routing table from a file. [Just the information about it's neighbours.] 
part-2) Sends it's routing table information to the neighbours.

I'm facing problem with the current implementation of part-2.

//data structures

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<thread>
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 10000
#define MAXCHAR 2048

int sockfd;
int bind_flag;
int sent_bytes;
int bytes_received;
char buffer[MAXCHAR];

socklen_t addrlen;
struct sockaddr_in server_address;
struct sockaddr_in client_address;
struct sockaddr_in dummy;


string ip1, ip2;
int cost;




struct routing_table_entry{
        string next_hop;
        int cost;
       routing_table_entry(){
   }


routing_table_entry(string next_hop, int cost){
    this->next_hop=next_hop;
    this->cost=cost;

}

};

map<string, routing_table_entry> routing_table;
```

The Routing Table Sender function

```
 void send_table_to_neighbor(){

    it = routing_table.begin();

    ostringstream message;

while(it!= routing_table.end()){

    if((it->first).compare((it->second).next_hop) ==0){ //neighbour check

        cout<<"Sending table to: "<<it->first<<endl;
        inet_pton(AF_INET,(it->first).c_str(),&server_address.sin_addr);
        cout<<"Neighbour IP: "<<it->first<<endl;
        nest = routing_table.begin();

        while(nest != routing_table.end()){
            message.clear();
            message.str("");
            // destination next hop cost
            message<< (nest->first)<<" "<<myIP<<" "<<(nest->second).cost<<" "; //destination

            string message_string = message.str();
            strcpy((char*)buffer_S, message_string.c_str());
            cout<<"Message string: "<<message_string<<endl;

            printf("Sending to: [%s:%hu]: %s\n", inet_ntoa(server_address.sin_addr), ntohs(server_address.sin_port), buffer_S);

            sent_bytes=sendto(sockfd, buffer_S, MAXCHAR, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

            int random = rand() % 2 + 1;
    //        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(random));

            nest++;
        }


      string terminate = "shutdown";
      strcpy((char*)buffer_S, terminate.c_str());

        printf("Sending to: [%s:%hu]: %s\n", inet_ntoa(server_address.sin_addr), ntohs(server_address.sin_port), buffer_S);

      sent_bytes=sendto(sockfd, buffer_S, MAXCHAR, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

   // cout<<buffer <<endl;

   }

    int random = rand() % 3 + 2;
  //  std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(random));
    it++;
}

return;
```

}

The Function to receive the table and update the table.

```
  void update_routing_table(){
       cout<<"My IP: "<<myIP<<endl;

    while(true){

    addrlen= sizeof(dummy);
    cout<<"Started reading:...."<<endl;

    bytes_received = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer_R, MAXCHAR , 0, (struct sockaddr*) &dummy, &addrlen);
    //bytes_received = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer_R, MAXCHAR , 0, (struct sockaddr*) &dummy, &addrlen);

    cout<<"Stop reading:...."<<endl;

    string data(buffer_R);

    printf("Received from: [%s:%hu]: %s\n", inet_ntoa(dummy.sin_addr), ntohs(dummy.sin_port), buffer_R);


    if(! data.compare("shutdown")){
        cout<<"----------------------"<<endl;
        printf("Received SHUTDOWN from: [%s:%hu]: %s\n", inet_ntoa(dummy.sin_addr), ntohs(dummy.sin_port), buffer_R);
        cout<<"----------------------"<<endl;
        _count++;

        }
    if(_count==3)
        break;

  istringstream data_buff(data);


    string dest, next_hop;
    data_buff>>dest>>next_hop>>cost;
     cout<<"Receiving: "<<dest<<" "<<next_hop<<" "<<cost<<endl;

    it= routing_table.find(dest);

    if(it != routing_table.end()){

        //update the table
        temp = routing_table.find(next_hop); //next_hop is my neigbour

        if((temp->second).cost + cost < (it->second).cost ){ // A-B-X , (A->B) + (B->X) < (A->X)
            //it->second = routing_table_entry(next_hop, cost);
            routing_table[it->first]=routing_table_entry(next_hop, (temp->second).cost + cost);
            cout<<"Inside."<<endl;
            cout<<dest<<" "<<next_hop<<" "<<cost<<endl;
            cout<<it->first<<" "<<(it->second).next_hop<<" "<<(it->second).cost<<endl;
            cout<<"DEBUG"<<endl;

            print_routing_table();

          //  send_table_to_neighbor();

        }


    }
    //int random = rand() %2 +1;
 //     std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(random));
}

  return;

}
```

Main function,

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


if(argc != 2){
    printf("%s <ip address>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}
//FILE* topo=freopen("topo.txt", "r", stdin);

ifstream file("topo.txt");

 myIP=string(argv[1]);

string hold;

while(getline(file, hold)){

    istringstream input(hold);
    input>>ip1>>ip2>>cost;

    if(!myIP.compare(ip1))

        routing_table[ip2]=routing_table_entry(ip2, cost); // destination ip2, next hop ip2

    else if(!myIP.compare(ip2))

        routing_table[ip1]=routing_table_entry(ip1, cost); //destination ip1, next hop ip1

    else{

            it= routing_table.find(ip1);

            if(it == routing_table.end())
                routing_table[ip1]= routing_table_entry("-", MAX);

            it= routing_table.find(ip2);


            if(it == routing_table.end())
                routing_table[ip2]= routing_table_entry("-", MAX);
    }
}

file.close();


print_routing_table();

it= routing_table.begin();

server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_port = htons(4747);

client_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
client_address.sin_port = htons(4747);
//client_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
inet_pton(AF_INET,argv[1],&client_address.sin_addr);

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
cout<< "Socket value "<<sockfd <<endl;
bind_flag = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &client_address, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

if(bind_flag==0)
    printf("successful bind\n");

    send_table_to_neighbor();
    update_routing_table();

cout<<"<<My IP is: "<<myIP<<endl;
print_routing_table();


close(sockfd);


return 0;

 }
```

Now, from the main function, I am calling i) send_table_to_neighbor() first then, ii) update_routing_table()  [Each router program will do this]

When I run all the router programs, not all of them are receiving all the sent data. Some sent data are never received. [This is without using any threads]

I have tried using threads (visible from the comments), but in that case, the routers don't receive the sent messages in order, so the "shutdown" message reaches before other messages do and they stop functioning 
[Shutdown message: After sending the total routing table to a neighbour,  I am sending a "shutdown" message to that neighbour so that it can stop expecting messages from that router. I'm checking if all the neighbours sent them shutdown, only then the router will stop executing "update_routing_table"]

Please, suggest me how  I can pass messages  from a number of routers to another number of routers in a way that each of them receive all the messages.

Topo.txt  : http://codepad.org/Z0cDGHvX
Setup file for virtual network interface: http://codepad.org/MDoJzpTx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how I can pass messages from a number of routers to another number of
>   routers in a way that each of them receive all the messages.

The answer to this question is very simple: just write the code to do this.

To your credit, you tried to do that, and you described the resulting problem thusly:

> When I run all the router programs, not all of them are receiving all
>   the sent data

All right, that's your problem statement. The next thing you wrote was:

> I have tried using threads (visible from the comments), but in that
>   case, the routers don't receive the sent messages in order,

And that's where you went wrong. You first described the problem as "not all of them are receiving all the sent data". If this is the case, then your next step should be is to figure out why that is, and then fix it.

Your next step should not be, "well, let me try a random change to the code, maybe if I use threads it'll work".

If you don't understand why your code isn't working, then trying every random change that you can think of is unlikely to be very productive. This is like trying to start your car, the car doesn't start, and you figure that, maybe, if you kick one of the rear tires, that'll get the car going.

No, you should, instead, figure out the precise reason why "not all of them are receiving all the sent data". Investigate using a debugger, or other tools that are available to you. Read any available technical documentation regarding what your code is doing. Once you know and understand why, then the next step will be to figure out what to do about it.

You showed only incomplete, isolated code fragments, instead of a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without a [minimum, complete, an verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) no definitive answer is possible. The only thing possible is to analyze any potential, and likely issues based solely on the code you have posted.

I see two potential problems with the shown code, that might explain your original problem.

## No guarantees of the number of bytes sent or received

The return value from `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` is not checked. Neither one of these functions guarantee that the requested number of bytes have been sent or received. See the respective functions' manual pages for more information.

## UDP is not a reliable protocol

It is not absolutely clear from the shown code whether you created `TCP` or `UDP` sockets. It appears to be `UDP` because you are using the network address parameters to these functions. The following assumes you are using `UDP`:

If you know enough to create `UDP` sockets, then you should already know that `UDP` does not guarantee datagram delivery. It is an unreliable protocol. That's the first thing you should've been taught, or the first thing any book that describes `UDP` will tell you. You are not guaranteed that your sent datagram will be delivered. Period. Full stop.

It doesn't matter if you use one thread, a thousand threads, if your code is written in C++, Perl, Python, or any other language. No matter what you do, you have no guarantees that anything you send will be received.

If you are, indeed, using `UDP` it is almost a certainty that this is your problem.

If you want to use `UDP`, and you need reliable, guaranteed datagram delivery, it is your responsibility to implement this as part of your application, on top of `UDP`. If you don't want to do this, use `TCP`.

And, on matter how you do it, you must always check the return value from `sendto()` and `recvfrom()`, and have appropriate means in place to handle the eventuality that the return value indicates that fewer bytes were sent or received.

P.S. Neither `sendto()` nor `recvfrom()` will tell you if your sent datagram was lost and could not be delivered. It's up to you to figure it out.

Comment: Now I provided all the code used for the router program. As I am using virtual network interfaces(on ubuntum on the same computer), I didn't think that sent data won't be received(that is, no packet should drop).